# Bind array/XML to WPF ListView/DataGrid

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, powershell, datagrid

I have a PowerShell array which if I export as XML it will look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<Objects>
   <Object>
      <Property Name="Server">Server1</Property>
      <Property Name="Issue">hard drive 0 failed</Property>
   </Object>
</Objects>
```

I want to have this array to be displayed in GUI. After googling I found that it's possible to use WPF for this goal, but I never worked with it before so I'm struggling with probably beginner questions:

1. How to correctly bind an array to ViewList to get columns automatically created and named as property name ("Server", "Issue" and so on)
2. I will no need to edit data, but want to have a button in each row which sends data from current row to Jira as new issue. I'm already have a code how to create Jira issue using PS and REST API, but don't know yet how to put a button inside ListView cell

After another day of googling I found that DataGrid is better suits my case as number of columns is autogenerated based on passed ItemsSource object.

Now I'm stuck on a new issue, here is my code:

```
$btn = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.Button
$dt = New-Object System.Windows.DataTemplate
$dt.VisualTree = New-Object System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory($btn)
$dgtc = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn
$dgtc.CellTemplate = $dt
$faults = Get-UcsFault -Severity critical | select @{n=’Server’; e={$_.Dn}},
          @{n=’Issue’;e={$_.Issue}}, 
          @{n=’Create Ticket’;e={[System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn]$dgtc}}
$result = New-Object System.Windows.Window -prop @{
   Content = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid -prop @{ItemsSource=$faults};}
$result.ShowDialog()
```

But instead of actual button I see a Class Name (i.e. System.Windows.Controls.Button) in last column

Comment: So if am right, you will have many <Object>, will you ? Each one will have a server and an Issue property, will they ? Will the Columns allways be Server and Issue ?

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, yeah, that's correct, I have a list with issues, so many objects. Columns are defined by me. I'll add my finding to this question below

Comment: From here, two ways (at least!). The first, I'd prefer would be to put the Windows C#/XAMl code in a WPF Library and use it. I think it 'll be easier. The second is to PowerShell the XAML ! I can help to a certain point,put I don't know how to subscribe to the click. To understand XAML, nearly every Tag is an object. i.e >DataGrid>, <Button>, <DataTemplate>, ... the exceptions are the tags with a dot inside :  <DataGrid.Columns> (=Property Columns of object Datagrid ). And of course all XML attributes (in red) are .Net properties. Special issue for {Binding ...} that are objects

Comment: Ok now I edit your question. I let you try,and edit if incorrect

Comment: After some few trys, I gave up, I really don't know how you can can create a UserControl in Powershell. This is needed if you want to translate the XAML DataTemplate in to C# (and then PS). Anyway, for your information, here is a link to file I made : http://1drv.ms/1OwsMDE. You really need to build a WPF lib with Visual Studio (there are some free express editions)

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, looks like I have a two ways: 1) Disregard Automatic comumn binding and bind column by column manually like in code that you provided; 2) Figure out how to present button in such format that default binder will recognize it. I'm trying to go with second option, and created a DataGrdiColumntTemplate for Button which is required as default binders do not have definition on how to bind a button. But unfortunately only class name is displaed as string in cell, not the button itself. P.S. Script in question is updated with my findings

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Here is a way to read data using Linq to XML in Code Behind of window :

```C#
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private ObservableCollection<ServerIssue> serverIssues;

    public MainWindow()
    {

        // Linq to XML for elegant Selections
        XElement doc = XElement.Load("serverissues.xml");
        var xmlServerIssues = from objectElt in doc.Descendants("Object")
                           let propertiesElts = objectElt.Elements("Property")
                           let serverElt = propertiesElts.FirstOrDefault(elt => elt.Attribute("Name").Value == "Server")
                           let issueElt = propertiesElts.FirstOrDefault(elt => elt.Attribute("Name").Value == "Issue")
                           select new ServerIssue {
                               Server = ((serverElt.FirstNode) as XText).Value,
                               Issue = ((issueElt.FirstNode) as XText).Value
                           };
        // store enumerated data in ObservableCollection<>
        // List<> would be fine but is less agile when adding/removing elements
        serverIssues = new ObservableCollection<ServerIssue>(xmlServerIssues);
        InitializeComponent();
        // Provide data to graphical Grid
        datagridIssues.ItemsSource = serverIssues;
    }
    private void SendToJIRA(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

2. Code for Layout of DataGrid, binding properties :

```XAML
<Window x:Class="XmlToDataGrid.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <DataGrid x:Name="datagridIssues" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Server}" IsReadOnly="true"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Issue}" IsReadOnly="true"/>
                <DataGridTemplateColumn >
                    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                            <Button Content="Send to JIRA" Click="SendToJIRA" Margin="10 4" Padding="5 3"/>
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
                </DataGridTemplateColumn>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

**Edit**

Here the translation in PowerShell. It 's not so obvious, even in C#.
I really encourage you to write such code in C#. You 'll have a compiler, a serious debugger.

```
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("PresentationFramework") | Out-Null

# $faults = Get-UcsFault -Severity critical | select @{n=’Server’; e={$_.Dn}},                                               
                    # @{n=’Issue’;e={$_.Issue}}, 
                    # @{n=’Create Ticket’;e={$bt}}                        
                    ######################################################################################

$serverIssue1 = New-Object psobject -Property @{ 
    Server="server1"
    Issue="issue1"
}
$serverIssue2 = New-Object psobject -Property @{ 
    Server="server2"
    Issue="issue2"
}

$serverIssues = New-Object System.Collections.Generic.List``1[Object]
$serverIssues.Add( $serverIssue1  ) 
$serverIssues.Add( $serverIssue2  ) 

$datagrid = New-Object Windows.Controls.DataGrid -prop @{
    AutoGenerateColumns=$FALSE; ItemsSource = $serverIssues;
    CanUserAddRows=$FALSE
    CanUserDeleteRows=$FALSE
}

#$datagrid.ItemsSource=$faults
# create the binding for a column
$bindingIssue = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding -prop @{ Path='Issue'}
# create the column
$columnIssue = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn -prop @{ IsReadOnly=$TRUE;Binding=$bindingIssue}
$datagrid.Columns.Add($columnIssue)
# create the binding for a column
$bindingServer = New-Object System.Windows.Data.Binding -prop @{ Path='Server'}
# create the column
$columnServer = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTextColumn -prop @{ IsReadOnly=$TRUE;Binding=$bindingServer}
$datagrid.Columns.Add($columnServer)

# create 3rd column : it s a template, more complicated ! Real WPF hardcore stuff
# not easy in C#, hard tests in PS !

$factory = New-Object System.Windows.FrameworkElementFactory([System.Windows.Controls.Button])
$factory.SetValue( [System.Windows.Controls.Button]::ContentProperty, "Send to Jira")
$thickness  = New-Object System.Windows.Thickness(10,5,10,5)
$factory.SetValue( [System.Windows.Controls.Button]::PaddingProperty, $thickness )
$factory.SetValue( [System.Windows.Controls.Button]::MarginProperty, $thickness )
# let's plug a callback when the button is clicked
$factory.AddHandler([System.Windows.Controls.Button]::ClickEvent, [System.Windows.RoutedEventHandler]{
    PARAM ([Object]$sender, [Windows.RoutedEventArgs]$e)
        # replace with code that sends to Jira
        # the DataContext is for the current line of DataGrid. It 's inherited by every component of the line 
        # so the button has a serverIssue DataContext
        $serverIssue = $sender.DataContext
        [System.Windows.MessageBox]::Show($serverIssue.Server);
})

$dataTemplate = New-Object System.Windows.DataTemplate -prop @{ VisualTree = $factory }
$columnButton = New-Object System.Windows.Controls.DataGridTemplateColumn -prop @{ IsReadOnly = $TRUE; CellTemplate = $dataTemplate }
$datagrid.Columns.Add($columnButton)

$result = New-Object System.Windows.Window -prop @{ Content = $datagrid }
$result.ShowDialog()
```

Regards

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, thx for great example, but as you can see I'm already mapped an array to DataGrid and data inside array was correctly handled and properly displayed by DataGrid. From my understanding that's a XAML way to do this and I'm looking how to do the same in code, could you help this?

Comment: So, Serguey, did you find time to have a look at my solution above. Itranslated every C# and XAML into PowerShell, so it's easy to use by you. I 'd really like to hear some good news

Comment: Hi Emmanuel, sorry didn't had a time to came back to this task for a week... thx a lot, your example is working as expected. But I'm probably incorrectly described in the question itself one important detail. In the $faults array which I'm using as ItemsSoruce I have a column named Ticket which contains Jira ticket number if ticket already created or "N/A" if no ticket found. So I need to show "Create ticket" button only in case if ticket not created

Comment: What is coming to my mind is overriding CellTamplateSelector to use different templates based on cell value. Also I saw an advise to add AutoColumnGeneration Event handler to change column template, but I think even there I need to deal with different cell templates in one column

Comment: Sergey, I answered your first question, then you changed the question, I answered again, and the question changed again, and I answered again ... and again and again, .... do you want me to write your project for free ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't want you to think something like this. I'll mark your aswer as correct and continue my research. Thx again

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you want to create a class based on your XML Object.

```
public class yourObject //Whatever you want to call it.
{
  public string Server {get;set;}
  public string Issue {get;set;}
  //ETC
}
```

---

Once you get your class setup, Id go through the XML file and get the data into a list.

```
        string filepath = Directory.GetParent(Environment.CurrentDirectory).Parent.FullName + @"\OBJECTS.xml"; 
       //Path to XML file

        List<yourObject> list = new List<yourObject>();
        var maps = from c in XElement.Load(filepath).Elements("Object")
                   select c;

        foreach (var item in maps)
        {
            var newObject= new yourObject();

            //Names of your nodes
            newObject.Server= item.Element("Server").Value;
            newObject.Issue= item.Element("Issue").Value;

            list.Add(newObject);
        }
        //Probably a good idea to make it an observable collection.
        objectList= new ObservableCollection<youtObject>();
        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            objectList.Add(item);
        }
```

---

Once it's in a list, and you dont care to bind to it, you can just set the Item source of the Datagrid or the listview, to that list

Comment: Hi Dylan, as I mentioned data is already in array, I exported it to XML to show it's structure. Could you add a code block, how to display data from objectList (from your example) in ListView or DataGrid (I don't care much about component as need Excel-like table). And thx for your help

Comment: Once you have the list available, Just set your grid to the list, yourDataGrid.Itemsource=objectList;

Comment: Sorry, I didn't mentioned, I'm already done this, so answered myself on first question. I've updated a question to include my findings, now struggling with button (second question)